# How to use pipline for checkin devops data

Tags: url

How to use pipline for checkin devops data.
How to use pipline for checkin devops data
How to use pipline for checkin devops data

Answer (score 0):

Because plus is not use in params... params change the plus in space

Comment: then how to solve this problem?

Comment: use  %2b insted of plus this will give you plus when fetching the params

Answer (score 0):

let assume the params is [www.somewebsite.com?name=%2bsomename](http://www.somewebsite.com?name=%2bsomename)

```
  const params = new URLSearchParams(props.location.search);

  console.log(params);
```

the console log look like this +somename